# Why is my responsive site zoomed in on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

So I've created a simple landing page for a fictional company so that I could try out `css-grid` and I've tried making the site responsive. First I tried without media queries but later I think media queries where necessary. The thing is that on the browser everything looks fine whenever I resize. Everything fits so to say. But when I access the site from my phone it is kinda zoomed in. The same can be seen when you try the site out in the devtools and choose different devices to try the site out.

I thought that this issue would be solved by adding the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` tag. But it didn't solve the issue.

[You can visit the site here and play around with it](https://konsvasi.github.io/logistics-company-landing-page/)

[and here is the repo where you can check out the code](https://github.com/konsvasi/logistics-company-landing-page)

Comment: For SO, it's best to make a minimal example that shows your problem and embed the problem. It's not just a help site--the question should have most or all that's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your site is hitting a minimum width. I opened it in a browser on my computer and resized the window and the words in the heading seem to be wrapping properly as the page gets smaller and smaller. However, when the window gets too small, they stop wrapping. I suspect this could be caused by a minimum width.

---

Looking at your css code in your repo, it looks like your `grid-template-columns` might be the cause of the minimum width. Perhaps this line:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(150px, 300px));`

For viewing the site on mobile, specifically, I would recommend having a single column all the way down the page. It's hard to put multiple columns next to each other on a mobile device such as a phone in portrait orientation without each column becoming "too squished".

Comment: Yeah, that must be it, the `grid-template-columns`. @ceindeg said the same thing while I was editing this answer.

Comment: So the article container has to be changed to a single column using a media query right? I was trying to get it to that automatically without using a media query but I'm a little confused about the min-content, max-content and minmax that make a grid responsive.

Comment: Yes, you would set it up so that, at a certain width, it switches from multiple columns to a single column. Here is a reference site about media queries for standard devices: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm doing now and it works. I guess I just wanted to avoid media queries and got tunnel vision. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS for `.articles-container` you have the line `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(150px, 300px));`.

This is setting the minimum grid column width of 150px. On a mobile screen this will be 3 x 150px so will be wider than the screen width.

Comment: Plus the 20px grid-gap too actually